# If condition not working for text strikethrough in iOS tableview ToDo app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, if-statement, core-data

I have an iOS ToDo app that is based on the iBook App Development with Swift. I extended it to use CoreData (to be able to sort by date). I also added a feature to strikethrough the taskTitleLabel when an isCompleteButton is toggled. Everything seems to work ok until the last item on the tableview is toggled complete, then toggled not complete. If a new item is added to the list after the toggled one, the title has the strikethrough applied without the isCompleteButton being selected.  Here's the code:

TaskCell.swift

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol TaskCellDelegate: class {
    func checkmarkTapped(sender: TaskCell) 
}

class TaskCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: TaskCellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var isCompleteButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var taskTitleLabel: UILabel!


    @IBAction func isCompleteButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.checkmarkTapped(sender: self)

    }
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        isCompleteButton.isSelected = !isCompleteButton.isSelected
    }
}
```

TasksTableViewController

```
    ...
 func checkmarkTapped(sender: TaskCell) {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender){
            let task = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as? Task
            task?.isComplete = !task!.isComplete
            coreDataStack.saveContext()
        }
    }
...
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell") as? TaskCell else { fatalError("Could not dequeue a celL")}

        cell.delegate = self

        let task = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! Task
        cell.taskTitleLabel.text = task.title
        cell.isCompleteButton.isSelected = task.isComplete

        if  task.isComplete {
            let strikeThroughTask = NSMutableAttributedString(string: task.title!)
            strikeThroughTask.addAttributes([
                NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor: UIColor.darkGray,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
            ], range: NSMakeRange(0, strikeThroughTask.length))
            cell.taskTitleLabel.attributedText = strikeThroughTask
        }

        if task.hasDueDate {
            if task.dueDate! < Date().startOfDay {
              cell.taskTitleLabel.textColor = .red
            } else if task.dueDate! > Date().startOfDay && task.dueDate! < Date().endOfDay {
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    cell.taskTitleLabel.textColor = .label
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    cell.taskTitleLabel.textColor = .black
                }
            } else {
                // future due date
                cell.taskTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 100/255.0, green: 100/255.0, blue: 100/255.0, alpha: 1)
            }
        } else {
            //no dueDate
            cell.taskTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 125/255.0, green: 125/255.0, blue: 125/255.0, alpha: 1)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

I am also using a NSFetchResultsController

```
extension TasksTableViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        let index = indexPath ?? (newIndexPath ?? nil)
        guard let cellIndex = index else { return }

        switch type {
            case .insert:
                tableView.insertRows(at: [cellIndex], with: .automatic)
            case .delete:
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [cellIndex], with: .automatic)
            case .update:
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [cellIndex], with: .automatic)
            default:
                break
        }
    }


    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

}
```

From AddTaskTableViewController

```
...
func updateTaskEntry() {
        guard let task = task else { return }

        task.title = taskTitleTextField.text
        task.isComplete = isCompleteButton.isSelected
        task.hasDueDate = hasDueDateSwitch.isOn
        if hasDueDateSwitch.isOn {
            task.dueDate = dueDatePicker.date
        } else {
            task.dueDate = nil
        }
        task.notes = notesTextView.text
        coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }

    func saveNewTask() {
        let task = Task(context: coreDataStack.managedObjectContext)
            task.title = taskTitleTextField.text
            task.isComplete = isCompleteButton.isSelected
            task.hasDueDate = hasDueDateSwitch.isOn
            if hasDueDateSwitch.isOn {
                task.dueDate = dueDatePicker.date
            } else {
                task.dueDate = nil
            }
            task.notes = notesTextView.text
            task.createdOn = Date()

            coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        guard segue.identifier == "saveUnwind" else {return}

        if navigationItem.title == "Add Task" {

            saveNewTask()

        } else if navigationItem.title == "Update Task" {

            updateTaskEntry()
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: why is the text in the titleLabel have the strikethrough without the isCompleteButton selected or task.isComplete? What am I missing?

Comment: Put a break point in `if task.isComplete` and see if the app stops running at that point. My initial thought is that you're `task.isComplete` is false, that or that or when you call `cell.taskTitleLabel.attributedText = strikeThroughTask` either your `cell`, your `taskTitleLabel`, your `attributedText` (very likely) are `nil`, that or your `strikeThroughTask` might be `nil` itself. Use some breakpoints and do some simple debugging.

Comment: @Pierce, thank you for your input. Setting a breakpoint at strikeThroughTask only stops the app if task.isComplete. The task appears in the last row with strikethrough text even though cell.taskTitleLabel.attributedText was not called. I'm still playing with breakpoints to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think half of the problem lies in this line where when preparing for cell reuse you set the isCompleteButton to its opposite state:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    isCompleteButton.isSelected = !isCompleteButton.isSelected
}
```

I think the state of the isCompleteButton for each of your tasks should be bound to your data model only.  It should not have to be modified in this function.  I would probably remove the function altogether.

And the other problem is, when you save a new task in saveNewTask(), you set the isComplete property based on whether that button is selected or not:

```
task.isComplete = isCompleteButton.isSelected
```

I would say this should be changed to:

```
task.isComplete = false
```

Explanation of the unexpected behavior:

I imagine if a cell is being prepared for reuse for a new task, and that cell's button was previously untoggled (isSelected: false), prepareForReuse() would make that value true since that is what your code currently does.  Then the new task would be saved with task.isComplete set to true. And that might be why the strikethrough is already applied.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I had thought that the prepareForReuse would restrict my problem to a new row added to the bottom, but after some testing and setting isComplete to false in saveNewTask, the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with help from here [Can't reset UILabel attributedText when a UITableViewCell is reused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628067/cant-reset-uilabel-attributedtext-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-reused)
I added taskTitleLabel.attributedText = nil to the prepareForReuse function.