# Attributed label won't go away when tableviewcell is reused in Swift/Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

For tableviews, I have never had an issue with a text label persisting after a cell is reused.

When you reload a tableview after the datasource has changed, the tableviewcells get the latest data and draw themselves accordingly.

However, I am now having this problem with an attributed label. After removing an item from the datasource so that the tableviewcell gets re-used the attributed label persists in the cell.  Needless to say, the leftover attributed label has nothing to do with what should be in the cell. It's just attached to the cell and won't go away.

The problem is described [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628067/cant-reset-uilabel-attributedtext-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-reused)

In the above answer, the person said he got rid of the attributed label by setting it to nil prior to doing anything with the regular text label.

```
transactionDescriptionLabel.attributedText = nil
transactionValueLabel.attributedText = nil
Or, if I reset the attributedText first, and then reset the text, it also works:

transactionDescriptionLabel.attributedText = nil
transactionValueLabel.attributedText = nil
transactionDescriptionLabel.text = nil
transactionValueLabel.text = nil
```

Setting the attributed label to nil seems to solve the problem for me but I have never had to set a regular textLabel to nil before and am trying to get my arms around why I would have to set the attribute label to nil.

When you have an attribute label, is it necessary to set it to nil when you dequeue the cell?  Or, apart from setting it to an empty string, what is the proper way to get it to disappear when you are no longer displaying it in the tableview?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I'd say it's because the author was mixing `NSAttributedString` + `NSString` on `.text` and `.attributedText`, and the `label` property was kind mixing it, keeping old values for attributes when setting only the `.text`: AVOID mixing them.

Comment: Point of order: You are setting the **contents** to nil, not setting the label to nil. setting the label to nil would look like this: `transactionDescriptionLabel = nil` (and you likely wouldn't want to do that, since you would lose access to the view, even though it would still be in the view hierarchy.)

Comment: I actually have two separate labels, one that I use for regular string and a second one that I use for the attributed string and I am fading one out and other in with alpha property. However, after fading out the attributed string and then removing the item from the tableview, the attributed string sticks around in the cell superimposed on the new label....

Comment: so it's okay to say attributedLabel.text = nil; That preserves the label?

Comment: You can just test it in Playgrounds, with: `label.text = "First Value"; label.attributedText = label.text?.strikedThrough() //from linked question; label.text = "Hello there"`, and show the `label` output each time, you'll see.

Comment: Ok. Thx.  Will confirm it that way.

Comment: Here an illustration: https://imgur.com/BjvDzFG I'd illustrate with the `UITextView` and its `typingAttributes`, that will keep at the "start" the attributes used by the first character if the `attributedText`, even if it the `attributedText` has been deleted).

Answer (score 1):

`label.attributedText` will have styling properties of the string as well.

Before reusing, I mean before setting the `attributedText` property even once, the styling property would be set to default. If you use a `xib/storyboard`, you can see the default style for the label in attribute inspector or if you have edited these values then you know it already.

Now, if you set `label.text = "This is just text"`. This takes the default styling provided.

And at some point if you have to assign

1. `label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Attributed text", attributes: someAttributes)`

So from now, if you reuse this label, and set just the text like
`label.text = "This is just text"`
This causes the label to reuse the styling provided in previous cases via `someAttributes`

So if there's a case where you reuse your cell and the label inside it has different styles in different rows, better always set the
`attributedText` property with you required attributes. *Like point 1*

Now, if you don't need the label entirely you can remove it from the view heirarchy by `label.removeFromSuperview()`(handle reuse carefully in this case, use this only when you are sure that you won't be reusing this view accessing the removed label)

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the exact same issue with `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName`. I have to underline some text in a `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell` only if a condition is met. After scrolling through the cell, the label keeps reusing the attributes.

I tried several workaround, by setting `label.text` and `label.attributedText` to `nil`, removing attributes etc... nothing worked.

Finally, I found the actual solution looking at `NSAttributedString` documentation (RTFM, is always the answer):

There are enums defined for underline, and strikethrough attributes :

**NSUnderlineStyleNone = 0x00**

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSAttributedStringKey const NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.0), ios(6.0));  // NSNumber containing integer, default 0: no strikethrough
UIKIT_EXTERN NSAttributedStringKey const NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.0), ios(6.0));      // NSNumber containing integer, default 0: no underline
```

---

In conclusion, the actual way to remove underline or strikeThrough attribute is to set it to `NSUnderlineStyleNone` or `0`.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
[attributeString setAttributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleNone)} range:(NSRange){0, [attributeString length]}];
label.attributedText = attributeString;
```